# How to fix file name encoding

Tags: filenames, wget, character-encoding

I scrapped a site with `wget`.

That site is in German and some of that pages had Ü,ü,Ö,ö,Ä,ä,ß in the URL.

Now some files have a very weird name.
For example one file is called `mirror.de/�%9Cbersicht.html`

Is there a way to run a command that changes that weird encoding to a proper one?

In the example case I would expect the following as a valid result `mirror.de/Uebersicht.html`

EDIT:
Output of L`C_CTYPE=C ls | grep bersicht.html | od -t x1`:

```
0000000 42 69 6e 61 72 79 20 66 69 6c 65 20 28 73 74 61
0000020 6e 64 61 72 64 20 69 6e 70 75 74 29 20 6d 61 74
0000040 63 68 65 73 0a
0000045
```

Comment: have you tried --restrict-file-names in wget ?

Comment: @jai_s no, but I'm going to try that.

Comment: `Ü` in UTF-8 in URL encoding is `%c3%9c`. What exact byte sequence does the URL consist of (your post has the `�` substitution character)? You have a local file now, right? What's the output of `LC_CTYPE=C ls | grep bersicht.html | od -t x1`?

Comment: @Gilles Added the output of the command you asked for.

Comment: Sorry, that isn't useful because grep printed `Binary file (standard input) matches`. I hadn't thought of that. `LC_CTYPE=C ls *bersicht* | od -t x1` or `echo *bersicht* | od -t x1` would give useful output. But Stéphane's analysis is probably correct, did you try his answer?

Comment: @Gilles Because of your and Stéphane effored, I managed to get it done.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chances are that if you just decode the %XX URI encodings, you'll get UTF-8 encoded characters. In `zsh`:

```
autoload zmv
LC_ALL=C zmv '(**/)(*%*)' '$1${2//(#b)%(??)/${(#):-0x$match}}'
```

If as noted by Gilles, that � substitution character is for a 0xc3 byte (which in iso8859-1 is a letter which would explain why it hasn't been URI-encoded contrary to 0x9c which is invalid in iso8859-1), then the above command would change your file name to `Übersicht.html`

Answer (score 3):

After decoding the `%XX` URI encodings to valid UTF-8, you could also have used `convmv -f utf-8 -t latin-1` to convert the character set of the filename.

That might be an useful alternative solution if `zsh` is not available.

Comment: Note that my `zsh` approach only does the URI decoding, not conversion of charset. I don't think the OP wants the file names in latin1. But in any case, `convmv` is indeed a useful tip if you need to convert the charset in the file name.